# Piranha Strike with Claws

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, natural-weapon

What is the interaction of Piranha Strike with creature using multiple Claw natural weapons? Since natural weapons are light weapons, I'm wondering it it would apply to all claw attacks in a full attack and if it would be at the full bonus (Claws being primary natural attacks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the interaction of Piranha Strike with creature using multiple Claw natural weapons? Since natural weapons are light weapons, I'm wondering it it would apply to all claw attacks in a full attack and if it would be at the full bonus (Claws being primary natural attacks).

Relevant text of the [feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/piranha-strike-combat/) quoted:

"Benefit: **When wielding a light weapon**, you can choose to take a -1 penalty on all melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks to gain a +2 bonus on **all melee damage rolls**. This bonus to damage is halved (-50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or **secondary** natural weapon."

The claw attack in question - being a primary natural weapon, as you say - would qualify for the full benefit from the feat.

Answer (score 6):

By RAW, you get full penalties and bonuses according to [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/piranha-strike-combat/).

> This bonus to damage is halved (-50%) if you are making an attack with
>   an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.

Neither claw is off hand and neither claw is secondary if you are using claw/claw. If, however, you are using weapon/claw then the claw would be secondary and would be at half bonus.

So, go buzzsaw on 'em.